# ag-Grid infinite scrolling with Relay Modern

Tags: reactjs, graphql, relay, ag-grid-react, relaymodern

I'd like to implement infinite scrolling using ag-Grid's `getRows` function.
This function calls a `successCallback` when data has been fetched from the server. I'm using Relay Modern and they expose a `loadMore` function to fetch additional items from GraphQL server. The issue here is that Relay will pass the new data to my component's props (a list in this case) and I won't be able to let ag-Grid know what is the new data that has been fetched (by passing the new items to the `successCallback`).

Has anybody here implemented anything similar?